# Limit interval between selected slider inputs

Tags: r, shiny

Given a `sliderInput`, I would like to be able to restrict the possible values that a user can select based on the length (range) between the selection. For instance, given a `sliderInput` with possible values 1:100, I would like to allow a user to select any range provided the difference between the first and last is less than 5.

The following does not work as expected

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput(
    "test_slider",
    "Test Me",
    value = c(1,2),
    min = 1,
    max = 100,
    step = 1
  ),
  textOutput("what_selected")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  observe({
    selected <- req(input$test_slider[1]):req(input$test_slider[2])

    
  
output$what_selected <- renderText(
  if(all(length(selected)>1,max(selected)-min(selected) > 5)){
    
    print("You selected a range that is greater than 5,
            choosing the first five")
    selected <- selected[1:5]
    
  }
  selected)
   
    
  })
}



shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52217484/10323798) which seems close but different to what I need. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38376395/10323798) seems most close but still a bit different.

The example in this question is a bit oversimplified but I imagine it is sufficient for reproducibility.

**EDIT**

The problem is I am not sure how to restrict the range to 1-5 without resetting the slider to 1:5. For example if I select 1-20, I need to set the slider back to 1:5. Also if for example I select 50:60, I need to select 50-55 and so on. An option is to do this in server but I would love the user to see the change.

**The following work as expected. However, the user does not immediately know that on the server side, we only selected the first five. I would have loved to reset the range to the new selected values and show a message below "Sorry, can only select the first five in the range".**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes, I need to select the first five values whenever the difference is greater than 5 but allow for future selections in any range.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is I am not sure how to restrict the range to 1-5 without resetting the slider to 1:5. For example if I select 1-20, I need to set the slider back to 1:5. Also if for example I select 50:60, I need to select 50-55 and so on. An option is to do this in server but I would love the user to see the change.

Comment: @akrun, I have edited, Thannks

Comment: Yes, this is the expected value. Any selection with more than five values should return just the first five.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I do understand your problem, but I'm not sure about your desired way to solve it:

You do not want to restrict the choices.
You do not want to just update the sliders on the server side, without the user noticing whats going on, correct?

Then the only thing I can think of is {shinyFeedback}. Just use the first five values, and if the range between min and max is larger than five, let the user know, but don't change the slider.

Would that be a way to go about it?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyFeedback)

shinyApp(ui = fluidPage(
  
  useShinyFeedback(), # include shinyFeedback
  
  br(),
  
  sliderInput(
    "test_slider",
    "Test Me",
    value = c(1,2),
    min = 1,
    max = 100,
    step = 1
  ),
  
  verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "result")
  
  ),
  
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    
    r <- reactiveValues(slider = NULL)
    
    observeEvent(input$test_slider, {
      
      if (input$test_slider[2] - input$test_slider[1] >= 5) {
        
        
        showFeedbackWarning(
          inputId = "test_slider",
          text = "Only the first five values will be selected."
        )
      
        r$slider <- input$test_slider[1] + c(0:4)
        
      } else {
        
        hideFeedback("test_slider")
        
        r$slider <- c(input$test_slider[1]:input$test_slider[2])
          
      }
      
    })
    
    output$result <- renderPrint(r$slider)
    
  })
```

Comment: Thank you, I think this is a good solution as it is not a popup. I think I will go with this.