# Restrict slider input min and max values from overlapping (range > 0)

Tags: r, shiny

I am using a sliderInput widget to allow the user to select a range of values by sliding to the min and max position on the slider. I want the size of said range to be restricted to twice the size of the step (i.e. min = 3, max = 3.2) because I will later create a different sliderInput which will allow the user to slide to a value inside this range.

I can't however restrict the sliders from overlapping, which results to range=0 (min=max).

Is there a way of doing this in Shiny? Any help would be appreciated.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Test UI"),
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            sliderInput("ph",
                        "Range of pH:",
                        min = 0,
                        max = 14,
                        value = c(0,14),
                        step = 0.1,
                        dragRange = TRUE)
        ),
        mainPanel()
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: So we want the range to be fixed to the size of 0.2 minimum? Maybe try `renderUI`.

Comment: One approach is dealt with here, automatically updating to reject 0-length selections: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52212688/setting-a-minimum-range-in-a-shiny-app-slider)

Comment: @zx8754 Yes, 0.2 minimum.

Comment: See the linked post by Paul.